# No blog excerpt in index.php

Tags: wordpress

To be brief, following a tutorial, I didn't get to the part of the "main content" yet so like I usually do, i jumped ahead and put the main content in the sidebar. So in my "php get_sidebar()" I have my main content and my aside. Even though it's not in it's ideal format, my page looks fine. Blogs are displaying and all is well. Mind you, my "php the_excerpt()" is in my main content but everything is still good. Then we get to the part where he says to create a home.php page and place my main content there which is bordered by the php get_header & php get_sidebar like it should. I thought easy enough a cut and past of my main content out of my sidebar and into the home.php (Basically copying everything from the index.php into the home.php with the extraction of my main content OUT of my sidebar and placed inside home.php)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section>
    THIS IS MY TRUNCATED MAIN CONTENT

    <div id="posts" class="regions">
        <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1"); ?>
        <h4><span>Blog</span> City</h4>
        <div id="post_content">
            <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <img src ="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?     >/images/midpic.jpg" width="200px" height="118px"/> 
            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar   Widgets')) : else : ?>-->
    <!-- All this stuff in here only shows up if you DON'T have any widgets active in this zone --> 
<!--<?php endif; ?>-->


</section> <!--End of Section-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So my problem is that the blog and date were displaying when it was incorrect but now that it's in the home.php and formatted correctly, the php the_date and the php the_excerpt is not displaying. Any specs as far as what page shows my blogs? and FYI I tried this in the index.php as well as home.php and no dice. But if I put my main content back in the sidebar all is well. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but what is home.php used for? Usually single post template files are called single.php.

Also, for full posts you should be using `<?php the_content(); ?>`.

Documentation on [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) and [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content).

Comment: well I'm assuming (because it's a tutorial) is that he just replacing index.php with home.php. But like I said, we can take home.php out of the equation and my problem still exists in index.php But I will try using <?php the_content(); ?>. He actually mad no mention of it. He actually deleted all of that stuff and told me to replace it wil my main content i.e. my code above.

Comment: `the_excerpt()` displays the manual excerpt that can be set in the single post editor. It then backs out to other options but I don't think any of them are the full post. `the_content` does have options to display an automatic excerpt but will display the full content on a single post template page.

Comment: well what's funny is that the permalink still displays. I just lose the date and the excerpt.

Comment: Just to check, I took that whole div id="posts" out and put it back in the sidebar() and all is well but taking it out and putting it back inside the index.php like shown above, doesn't work for me.

Comment: That has something to do with the CSS file(s) for your theme. Look for "posts" and/or "regions" in there.

Comment: I was thinking as much but I don't see how and it's especially confusing that the permalink shows but not the date and the excerpt. I even changed the <p> tags just to check and see if I had a related css issue but nothing. The blog excerpt and date just doesn't display in index.php.

Comment: It has nothing to do with CSS. the_excerpt and the_date need to be used in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). There is a query, but no actual Loop.

Comment: maiorano84 is correct; even on a single page template the Wordpress loop is usually used. Otherwise, you can use `get_the_date()` and `get_permalink()` but those are usually used for more specialized cases rather than displaying them on the page.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help and pointing me in the right direction. I did do the loop and tweaked it a bit since I only had one post (still testing) and I pulled out the while loop since that was causing the one post to loop over and over. It's working although I don't think my code will suffice in the long run but at least I know about the loop which will help me going forward. Thank you again. This is my new code btw:

Comment: <div id="posts" class="regions">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1"); ?>
  <h4><span>Blog</span> City</h4>
  <div id="post_content">
   <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
   <img src ="<?php  bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/midpic.jpg" width="200px" height="118px"/> 
    <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
    </div>